# How do I make a generic onclick event handler for all buttons on my form?

Tags: vb.net, vba

I have 10 buttons on my form and I was wondering if anyone can help me write one onClick handler for all of them.

Comment: Nothing specifically, can you help? @saamorim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Properties window of a button, switch to event view and enter a name for the Click handler that is not tied to the specific button (in order to make it clear that it is an event handler that is not specific for a single control).
- Hit Enter to create the event handler and implement it.
- Select the other buttons one after the other and select the event handler you have created before in the Combobox of the Properties window.

In the event handler, you can cast the sender parameter to a Button and by that have access to the button that was clicked.

```
Dim clickedBtn = TryCast(sender, Button)
If clickedBtn IsNot Nothing Then
    ' Do something with the button
End If
```

Of course, the differences should not be very big - a long list of IF/SELECT CASE is not a good alternative for different event handlers for the buttons that call a common method in the background.